# C, Python, ctypes exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Tags: python, c, ctypes

C code(DLL)

```
#include <math.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct Doc
{
    wchar_t path[512];
    int r;
    int g;
    int b;
};

struct Docs
{
    struct Doc docs[1000000];
};

struct Color
{
    int r;
    int g;
    int b;
};

float distance(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e, int f)
{
    return sqrt((a-b)*(a-b)+(c-d)*(c-d)+(e-f)*(e-f));
}

struct Doc main(long len, struct Color c, struct Docs ds)
{
    long near = 1000000;
    long l;
    struct Doc f_d;
    for (l = 0; l < len; l++){
        struct Doc d = ds.docs[l];
        float dist = distance(c.r, d.r, c.g, d.g, c.b, d.b);
        if (dist < near){
            near = dist;
            f_d = d;
        }
    }
    return f_d;
};
```

Python code

```
class Doc(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("path", ctypes.c_wchar_p),
                ("r", ctypes.c_int),
                ("g", ctypes.c_int),
                ("b", ctypes.c_int)]

class Docs(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("docs", Doc * 1000000)]

class Color(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("r", ctypes.c_int),
                ("g", ctypes.c_int),
                ("b", ctypes.c_int)]

structure = ctypes.CDLL('st.dll').main
structure.restype = Doc
structure.argstypes = (ctypes.c_long, Color(), Docs(),)
```

After calling main function from python it drops with exit code `-1073741819`
After `exe` execution returns `"Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)"`
I think it is because of memory allocation or something like that.

Comment: Well, for one thing, `main` in C must be declared as returning `int`; you can't have it return a `struct Doc`, nor can you declare it as just taking whatever arguments you want.

Comment: In C: `wchar_t path[512];`, in python: `("path", ctypes.c_wchar_p)`. I haven't used ctypes but this seems wrong to me. Shouldn't it be `ctypes.c_wchar * 512`?

Comment: Changed ctypes.c_wchar_p to ctypes.c_wchar * 512, Python says Memory Error

Comment: Tried to decrease 1000000 to 100000 and 512 to 128, Python says OSError: exception: access violation reading 0x009F4000

Comment: It should be `c_wchar * 512`, as noted above. The structures should be passed by reference, i.e. change the function signature to `long len, struct Color *c, struct Docs *ds`. In Python it's `structure.argtypes =  (c_long, POINTER(Color), POINTER(Docs))`. You might want to redesign to move the `len` parameter into the `Docs` structure.

Comment: From a design perspective, I think the first field of `Docs` should be a `size_t length` that provides the number of elements. Then make the `doc` field a `struct Doc *` (i.e. `POINTER(Doc)` in Python). Avoid magic numbers such as 1000000. A 32-bit process probably doesn't have over a gigabyte of contiguous free address space to store a million `Doc` records.

Comment: Used Pointers and it finally works!