# Keras Model Failing to Compile: Exit Code "-1073741819 (0xC0000005)"

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, pycharm, keras

Goal: train a neural net using keras with tensorflow backend. Here is the script:

```
import pandas as pd
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import *

training_data_df = pd.read_csv("sales_data_training_scaled.csv")

X = training_data_df.drop('total_earnings', axis=1).values
Y = training_data_df[['total_earnings']].values

# Define the model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(50, input_dim=9, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')

# Train the model
model.fit(
    X,
    Y,
    epochs=50,
    shuffle=True,
    verbose=2)

# Load the separate test data set
test_data_df = pd.read_csv("sales_data_test_scaled.csv")

X_test = test_data_df.drop('total_earnings', axis=1).values
Y_test = test_data_df[['total_earnings']].values

test_error_rate = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test, verbose=0)
print("The mean squared error (MSE) for the test data set is: {}".format(test_error_rate))
```

When running the above code in pycharm (v2017.2.3) and using python 3.5 (since tensorflow requires it), I reveive the following error:

"Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)"

I have looked extensively for a solution for this to no avail. One post suggested that the training data may contain non-numeric values - not the case. Additionally, the following links have failed to turn up a consistent solution:
[I am unable to run my python code and get "Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34286282/i-am-unable-to-run-my-python-code-and-get-process-finished-with-exit-code-1073)
[C, Python, ctypes exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31565099/c-python-ctypes-exit-code-1073741819-0xc0000005)

I'm stuck...

Comment: This is a broad Windows error, I guess it could be a whole host of things e.g. http://www.errorlive.com/exception-code-0xc0000005

Comment: This is a PyCharm issue on Windows, see [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-17069).

Comment: just try sublime text